# Registration values get lost after action script process. How to prevent it?

Tags: php, forms, validation, refresh, registration

i've encountered a problem and cannot find the solution. I'm developing a website and found a problem during registration. I've got my form set up in a php page(registration.php)  to  make some action after i've pressed the submit button which  is processed by the registrationCheck.php. 
When processing it i'm cheking for errors like:

```
if (empty ($korIme)) {
$errors['username'] = "Niste unijeli korisničko ime!";
} 
else{
    if(strlen($korIme)<$minLengthKor){
        $errors['username'] = "Korisničko ime mora sadržavati više od 6    znakova!";       
    }
    else{
        if(strlen($korIme)>$maxLength){
            $errors['username'] = "Korisničko ime mora sadržavati manje od 20 znakova!";            
        }
        else{
            if (preg_match ('/[$#()&<>%\*\,\.]/', $korIme)) {
              $errors['username'] = "Korisničko ime ne smije sadržavati specijalne znakove!";
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

As you  can see after i check  for errors  i write them into variable $errors which  is than echoed in the form.  If there are no errors i send the mail  and update the database, but if there are errors i include the registration form so the user can see his errors:

```
include"registration.php";
```

The problem I have now is that I lose the values the users wrote in the input fields. For example if the username is correctly entered on submit the  error won't show up, but the input value get's lost and the user has to enter it again.

Same thing with the errors, if it's wrong the error pops up  but the value is gone, so the user can't change it and he has to write it again.

**How do I  keep those values so they can be changed instead of reentered?**

I'm not sure if storing the values into sessions is the way too go since there are alot of values and i'm not sure how will it interact with changing and refreshing of the page via action script.

This is my first post here so I  hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Sessions work fairly well. The thing is that you can put arrays into session variables as well. The easiest would be to do something like `$_SESSION['previousPOST'] = $_POST;`

Comment: Yes, but if i store it that way how will i get them into  the input fields when the page reloads(gets included)?

Comment: Something like this:
`<input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['previousPOST']['field1']; ?>">`

Comment: Is there a way too send hugs in here? :D   Works fine, thanks ^^  I don't know how i overlooked the fact you  can store arrays in session. And i totally forgot about the value.
Thank you  once again :)

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it worked :) You can upvote the comment, but that's about as close as it gets to hugging :)